# MariaDB change the reserved key word

Tags: open-source, mariadb

Is it possible to change the reserved keyword of an Open source system like MariaDB, (or why not Linux kernel), adding some salt to reserved keyword, that is necessary for unique objectives "more secured"?

In the case of MariaDB or PostgreSQL, the select query will be like

```
saltSELECT * saltFROM anyTable saltWHERE ID=1 saltUNION
```

any stranger user, will be really in MARS, if is it possible how can I do?

Comment: Why, if it is to prevent SQL injection, then you should just use parametrize queries, not make your life (and that of others in this project) a living hell.

Comment: hhhhhhhhhh, i am so alone in the project, no just to be sure, i find in client/mysql.cc source all commandes, wil be sufisant?

Comment: Your plan seems very insecure -- loose 'salt' and all is lost.

Comment: Every time there are new  security breachs, yah salt or changing all reserved key work seem to be perfect to outside users!